# soapUi: possible to send list of parameters to test case

Tags: groovy, soapui

Is it possible to send a list of parameters to a test case / step in soapUI? I want to perform some database validation, and I would like to be able to pass a list of the expected values to the test case and / or step that performs the validation.

I know it's possible to send single parameters ("properties") to a test case, but I don't think that's good enough for this use case. My idea is to write a single "test case" that performs the validation that can be called from other test cases, and they pass in the values they expect to find in the database.

Comment: You may use groovy script in free edition of soapui to loop through your data. Check this https://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/groovy-datasource-teststep-dataloop-teststep-using-groovy-in-soapui/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a similar issue. We need to run multiple XML-files as source files for the sequence of requests. We got about 15 steps in the test, and the only thing that changes is the initial XML.

We solved this by using groovy to set a propperty to a comma seperated list, then pick the first element, remove it from the list, and run the tests. In the end, we return to the "pick first element from list"-step if the propperty is not empty.

This is a goto implementation of a basic loop, and we would prefer to do this differently, but we have not figured out how to (we run soapUI via maven2).

Answer (score 2):

If you can generate the list of Random parameters through Groovy script then the best solution is: Through groovy script set the property field's value and pass this value into request using property transfer. The property field value will change at each and every run of the groovy script.

Now run the request in loop in groovy script.
So we can able to run the one test request multiple times with different parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using soapUI Pro,  you can create a data source step > request step > dataSource loop step.

dataSource step can take excel, XML, grid as the soure. You need to create a property and select the type of the source.

The next step is running the request.

Then you should create a dataSource loop step. This steps returns to the dataSource until running all the request.

Please check [soapui documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/functional-tests.html)

if you are not using soap Pro version, creating a groovy script is the solution as described with the previous answer.